# Randomly output text from array to view - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, output

Randomly output text from array to view - RAILS

Answer (score 3):

It is not really well formated question ... You should be more precise about what you want, what you are using, etc.

Assuming you are using Rails 3, ERB for HTML generation:

```
# in your controller:
file_as_array = IO.readlines('filename.txt')
random_line = rand(file_as_array.size)
@my_random_string = file_as_array[random_line]

# in your view:
<%= @my_random_string %>
```

Comment: You can use [#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) on the array.

Comment: @PittacusLore Maybe if you gave us more to go on instead of a one sentence question title, we could help. Can we see code? What error are you running in to? What have you tried? What are you using? ERB, HAML? What Ruby and what Rails versions? Etc.